# Python script to shutdown system doesn't work in cron

Tags: cron, python

A python script to shutdown system works fine from the terminal but doesn't work when included in crontab. The script is called by cron but ends with an error '*shutdown command not found*'or '*init 0 command not found*'. I am using fedora 17 and the script is executed from root's crontab.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('shutdown')
os.system('init 0')
```

Comment: i rather call it in crontab as 'python shutdown.py' with env set in cron. All other python script work fine except this one and in particular the shutdown command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the first line of your snippet is supposed to be something like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

or, if you also make sure you set an appropriate value for `PATH` in your crontab:

```
#!/bin/env python
```

What does your crontab entry look like? Don't forget that `cron` sets a very limited environment, so you will need to provide the full path to the script file so that `cron` can find it.

Additionally, python probably can't find `shutdown` when called from `cron`, because it will inherit `cron`'s limited environment. Try providing the full path to the `shutdown` command in your `os.system()` call.

Comment: It is usually preferred to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as that will use the python from PATH instead of a specific one. (Assuming that PATH is set correctly, which it may not be in a crontab)

Comment: So, for use within a crontab, then, the preferred approach is an explicit path, no?

Comment: I would argue that the preferred approach is to fix your PATH with another crontab line :)

Comment: Yuh, you're probably right! I know all about the portability concerns, etc, but as I only use FreeBSD, where everything is always in the same place, it's not really enough of a concern to make me break my lazy habits! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: calling _os.system('/sbin/shutdown')_ fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Your PATH isn't what you're expecting it to be.  According to the (Debian version of the) crontab(5) man page, the PATH environment variable is set to `/usr/bin:/bin` for programs run from cron.  You can change this by adding a `PATH=` line to the top of your crontab, for example:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This will change the path for all crontab entries below the PATH= line, up to the next PATH= line.  See the [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) man page for more details.